# Error occured during changing for loop to .apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am currently working on finding position(row index, column index) of maximum cell in each column of a dataframe.
There are a lot of similar dataframe like this, so I made a function like below.

```
def FindPosition_max(series_max, txt_name):  
# series_max : only needed to get the number of columns in time_history(Index starts from 1).
    
    time_history = pd.read_csv(txt_name, skiprows=len(series_max)+7, header=None, usecols=[i for i in range(1,len(series_max)+1)])[:-2]   
    
    col_index = series_max.index
    row_index = []
    for current_col_index in series_max.index:
        row_index.append(time_history.loc[:, current_col_index].idxmax())
           
    return row_index, col_index.tolist()
```

This works well, but takes too much time to run with a lot of dataframes. I found on the internet that .apply() is much more faster than for loop and I tried like this.

```
def FindPosition_max(series_max, txt_name):
    time_history = pd.read_csv(txt_name, skiprows=len(series_max)+7, header=None, usecols=[i for i in range(1,len(series_max)+1)])[:-2]    
    
    col_index = series_max.index
    row_index = pd.Series(series_max.index).apply(lambda x: time_history.loc[:, x].idxmax())
     
    return row_index, series_max.index.tolist()
```

And the error comes like this,

```
  File "C:\Users\hwlee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 844, in _list_of_series_to_arrays
    indexer = indexer_cache[id(index)] = index.get_indexer(columns)

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_indexer'
```

I tried to find what causes this error, but this error never goes away. Also when I tested the codes inside the function separately, it works well.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank u!

Comment: If you're looking for the index of the maximum value, why don't you use `time_history.idxmax()`?

Comment: I didn't know I can use like that. Thank u! But anyway it still doesn't work, and error is same.

Comment: I can't say anything to the error (you should add the full traceback to the question). But you could make the first version a bit more efficient if you replace the `for`-loop with a list comprehension.